# How can I solve "Connection refused: connect"

Tags: java, networking

I'm trying to make a connection between a client and server in java but when I run the server it gives a "Connection refused: connect" I don't know what to do and I'm really new to java networking can you please help me? here's my server code:

```
class reserver {


static int serverPort = 6667;
static int serverPort1 = 6668;
static String Message,input;
String ip = "127.0.0.1";

public reserver(){

    try{
        InetAddress ipAddress = InetAddress.getByName(ip);
        Socket socket = new Socket(ipAddress,serverPort);
        OutputStream sout = socket.getOutputStream();
        InputStream sin = socket.getInputStream();
        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(sout);
        out.writeUTF(input);
        out.flush();


    }catch(IOException e){
        System.out.print(e.getMessage());
    }   
}
public static void main(String [] args){
    new reserver();
    try{

            ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(serverPort1);

            int i = 0;
        while(true){
            i++;
            Socket socket = ss.accept();
            OutputStream sout = socket.getOutputStream();
            InputStream sin = socket.getInputStream();
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(sin);
            DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(sout);
            input = in.readUTF();

            System.out.println("Message [" + i + "]" +input);

        }

    }catch(IOException e){
        System.out.print(e.getMessage());
    }   

}
```

}

And here's my clients code:

```
class reclient {


String ip = "127.0.0.1";
static int serverPort = 6667;
static int serverPort1 = 6668;
static String Message,input;


public reclient(){

    try{

        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter Text: ");
        input = s.nextLine();


        InetAddress ipAddress = InetAddress.getByName(ip);
        Socket socket = new Socket(ipAddress,serverPort);
        OutputStream sout = socket.getOutputStream();
        InputStream sin = socket.getInputStream();
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(sin);
        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(sout);
        out.writeUTF(input);
        out.flush();

    }catch(IOException e){
        System.out.print(e.getMessage());
    }       
}
public static void main(String [] args){
    new reclient();
    try{

            ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(serverPort1);
            int i = 0;
        while(true){
            i++;
            Socket socket = ss.accept();
            OutputStream sout = socket.getOutputStream();
            InputStream sin = socket.getInputStream();
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(sin);
            DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(sout);
            input = in.readUTF();

            System.out.println("Message [" + i + "]" +input);

        }

    }catch(IOException e){
        System.out.print(e.getMessage());
    }   

}
```

}

Comment: Having trouble understanding why you use 2 socket connections for both client and server.

Comment: Also please post the full stack trace so we can see what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your code is swapped for server and client.

Look at :
[how do i connect to the server socket using the ip address and port number( client is running on a different machine than server)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27003907/how-do-i-connect-to-the-server-socket-using-the-ip-address-and-port-number-clie)