# How to connect to java server (socket) using internet

Tags: java, android, sockets

I'd read a tutorial from [here](https://github.com/aboullaite/Multi-Client-Server-chat-application). It is chat application made using java for server side and client as well and android as client. Its running good without any error just need to connect on ip address of server but my question is, can i use it over internet as well as over wifi? if yes then how?

Comment: I think, if your server just have been a static IP , this will work.

Comment: 1. Yes, 2. `if yes then how?` ---> Too broad.

Comment: I found duplicate question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27003907/how-do-i-connect-to-the-server-socket-using-the-ip-address-and-port-number-clie

Comment: "can i use it over internet as well as over wifi?" Apples and oranges ... "Wifi" can be used for In**tra**net as well as In**ter**net. Whether you can reach your server from your android device via in**ter**net depends on whether your server is reachable in the internet. So you'll need to have either a domain and port that will redirect you to the server or a public IP of that server. If it is reachable in the internet, it should be irrelevant if you connect via wifi or carrier (3G, 4G, ... ) Mind that some Androids cannot handle IPv6.

Comment: @Fildor can i use port forword here? and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just answering my own question for helping other person who's new to this thing. It's very easy, it can be done just using `ngrok` or can be done using port forwarding using router if it has Static public IP.

Comment: How would u create an app that would do that then??

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you should use Hotspot for connect over wifi.
use this https://github.com/nickrussler/Android-Wifi-Hotspot-Manager-Class/tree/master/src/com/whitebyte/wifihotspotutils

for connect over wifi hotspot in android client.