# Basic Client-Server Programming in Java using sockets

Tags: java, eclipse, sqlite, sockets, websocket

in my project I made a basic client-server communication system. Client is an android app and server is below in the form of .jar file which i programmed within eclipse.Communication within client and server works perfectly as long as connection is local or *localhost* - but now i wanted to extend the class functionality so that it can connect to a specific IP address and specific port number - after that it should support multiple connections!!! I am not really sure where to make changes here!!!!

```
public class MinimalServer {
ServerSocket s;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {           
        Database database = new Database();
        MinimalServer server = new MinimalServer();
        server.listAvailableInterfaces();
        InetAddress address;
        do{
            address = server.getAvailableAddress();
        } while(address==null);
        server.initialize(address);
        server.serverRoutine(database);
    } catch (IOException | SQLException e) {}
}

InetAddress getAvailableAddress() throws IOException{
    int result=0;
    NetworkInterface resultName=null;
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    do{
        System.out.println("Please type in the interface index you would like to start the server onto:");
        result = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
        if(NetworkInterface.getByIndex(result)!=null){
            System.out.println("Your choice was "+ NetworkInterface.getByIndex(result)+"\n");
            resultName = NetworkInterface.getByIndex(result); 
        }
    } while(resultName==null);
    Enumeration<InetAddress> e1 = resultName.getInetAddresses();
    InetAddress adr = null;
    while(e1.hasMoreElements()){
        InetAddress elem = e1.nextElement();
        if(elem.getAddress().length==4)
            adr=elem;
    }
    if(adr==null)
        System.err.println("No available IPv4 Address found on selected Interface!!");
    return adr;
}
void serverRoutine(Database database) throws IOException, SQLException{
    Socket socket = null;
    while(true) {
        try {
            socket = s.accept();
            System.out.println("Socket: "+socket.toString());
        } catch(SocketTimeoutException e1){}
        if(socket!=null){
            BufferedReader dis = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream(),"UTF-8"));
            while(dis.ready()){
                database.addCommand(dis.readLine());
            }
            database.executeTransaction();
        }
    }
}
void initialize(InetAddress address) throws IOException{
    s = new ServerSocket(50000,10,address);
    s.setSoTimeout(200);
    System.out.println("Server here : "+s.getInetAddress().getHostAddress()+":"+s.getLocalPort());
}
void listAvailableInterfaces() throws SocketException{
    Enumeration<NetworkInterface> e = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
    int total=0;
    System.out.println("Available Network interfaces: \nID\t--------\tIndex");
    while(e.hasMoreElements()){
        total++;
        NetworkInterface a = e.nextElement();
        System.out.println(a.getName()+"\t---------\t"+total);
        Enumeration<InetAddress> adr = a.getInetAddresses();
        while(adr.hasMoreElements())
            System.out.println("\tIP: "+adr.nextElement().toString());
    }
}
}
```

And this is the database;

```
public class Database {
Connection connection = null;
Statement statement;   
public Database(){
    try {
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:sample.db");
        statement = connection.createStatement();
        connection.setAutoCommit(false);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e1){
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public Statement addCommand(String command) throws SQLException{
    System.out.println(command);
    Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
    statement.setQueryTimeout(300);
    statement.executeUpdate(command);
    return statement;
}
public void executeTransaction() throws SQLException{
    connection.commit();
}
}
```

As you can see that I can specify the port number - means set it constant! How to set the IP address tho ( not local) ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You cannot explicitly set the IP address of the server or database as the internal IP is set by your router, and your external IP is set by your ISP. In order to connect on your local network you need to specify the IP of the server in the client application when you connect.

find the line in your client code that looks similar to:

```
Socket socket = new Socket(server_IP, server_Port);
```

then substitute the `server_IP` parameter for the IP of the server.

have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27003907/) Stack overflow question it might be of some help.